# Category/subcategory(/subsubcategory*) routing in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm building a new website in ASP.NET Core MVC, using version 3.1. One of my requirements is to offer a products catalogue, where items can be grouped into categories, sub categories, sub sub categories, and so on.

These categories should be represented in URLs in a user-friendly way, and should be nestable. For example, I would like to use the following URL pattern for categories and subcategories:

```
site/catalog/fashion.html
site/catalog/fashion/men.html
site/catalog/fashion/men/summer-wear.html
site/catalog/fashion/men/summer-wear/jeans.html
```

Once the "blue shorts" item has been chosen from the category/subcategory view, I'd like to have the following URL structure in place:

```
site/catalog/fashion/men/summer-wear/jeans/blue-shorts.html
```

I'm currently reading up on how routing is supposed to work in MVC, but it's doing my head in. There's a lot of information out there and I'm not quite sure which would be the right approach for my requirements.

How do I go about setting up routes which allow me to have an unlimited level of categories?

Answer (score 0):

Using `MapDynamicControllerRoute` and the `DynamicRouteValueTransformer`, it's possible to intercept the routing request and dynamically adapt which controller/action combination is being invoked by the framework.

Blog post detailing this:
https://www.strathweb.com/2019/08/dynamic-controller-routing-in-asp-net-core-3-0/

Sample code here:
https://github.com/filipw/Strathweb.Samples.DynamicControllerRouting